# Syntax – can be a class method called at New without a helper variable?

Tags: vb.net, methods, syntax, constructor, call

Having sample trivial class

```vb
Class A
    Property Property1 As Integer = 5
    Sub Action1()
        Debug.Print(Property1.ToString())
    End Sub
End Class
```

I can always call `Action1()` like

```vb
Dim instanceA As New A
instanceA.Action1()
```

**But can I call the method without using the variable?** Something like

```vb
(New A).Action1()
```

I'm getting syntax error at the 1st character when attempting that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you get a syntax error is that a line of VB code cannot begin with the `New` keyword.  I find that the best way around that is to use the otherwise useless `Call` keyword:

```
Call New A().Action1()
```

Comment: Upon your answer I've found that exactly the above case is covered in [Call statement documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxz296wz.aspx). There is one more case which always requires using `Call`. It is `Call (Sub() Console.Write("Hello"))()`.